# Time independent perturbation theory for a 1D simple harmonic oscillator system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, approximations

I have been looking through my notes and it says in a footnote that the approximation of energy levels using perturbation theory is more accurate when the energy shift of the energy levels due to the perturbation is much less than the energy levels. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Because perturbation theory works best when the perturbation is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the result of a first order perturbation calculation.  In general, perturbation calculations can be carried out to any order and the accuracy depends on the rapidity of convergence of the series. The first term is the unperturbed energy of the state and the second term is the result of the first order calculation.  If the second term is much smaller than the first it is a signal of rapid convergence which suggests high accuracy.

Comment: One small addition to my answer above.  In some situations a perturbation will not contribute in first order (usually due to symmetry considerations) and one needs to go to second order to get an idea of the magnitude of the correction.  In this case, the null result from the first order calculation is not indicative of the rapidity of convergence.

Comment: I know, I just decided to do it this way.